# Improve BigQuery case insensitive search performance

Tags: performance, google-bigquery

> **The BigQuery team strikes again**: This question is not longer relevant, as the results with LOWER() are as fast as with REGEX() now.

---

Processing ~5GB of data with BigQuery should be super fast. For example the following query performs a case insensitive search in 18 seconds:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE 
  LOWER(text) LIKE '%bigquery%' # 18s
```

Usually BigQuery is faster than this, but the real problem is that adding new search terms makes this query considerably slower (almost a minute with 3 search terms):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE 
  LOWER(text) LIKE '%bigquery%' OR LOWER(text) LIKE '%big query%' # 34s

#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE 
  LOWER(text) LIKE '%bigquery%' OR LOWER(text) LIKE '%big query%'
  OR LOWER(text) LIKE '%google cloud%' # 52s
```

How can I improve my query performance?

Answer (score 16):

> **Note from the team:** Stay tuned! Very soon BigQuery will turn this
> advice irrelevant.

## BigQuery performance tip: Avoid using `LOWER()` and `UPPER()`

`LOWER()` and `UPPER()` operations have a hard time when dealing with Unicode text: each character needs to be mapped individually and they can also be multi-bytes.

## Solution 1: Case insensitive regex

A faster alternative: Use `REGEX_MATCH()` and add the case insensitive `(?i)` modifier to your regular expression

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE 
   REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)bigquery') # 7s

#  REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)bigquery')
#   OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)big query') # 9s

#  REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)bigquery') 
#   OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)big query') 
#   OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)google cloud') # 11s
```

Performance is much better this way:

- 1 search term: 18s down to 8s
- 2 search terms: 34s down to 9s
- 3 search terms: 52s down to 11s.

## Solution 2: Combine regexes

Why do 3 searches when a regular expression can combine many into 1?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(bigquery|big query|google cloud)') # 7s
```

3 terms in 7s - nice.

## Solution 3: Transform to bytes

This is uglier, but shows that `UPPER()` and `LOWER()` perform way better when dealing with individual bytes - for equivalent results in these searches:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE 
  LOWER(CAST(text AS BYTES)) LIKE b'%bigquery%'
  OR LOWER(CAST(text AS BYTES)) LIKE b'%big query%' 
  OR LOWER(CAST(text AS BYTES)) LIKE b'%google cloud%' # 7s
```

---

## *LOWER() is slower. Use the regex (?i) modifier instead.*

*If this worked for you, please feel free to comment with your performance improvements*.

Comment: Thx Elliot Brossard for tips!

Comment: shorter solution 2 (similar performance): 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(big( )?query|google cloud)')

Comment: yes - but only because I picked similar strings for this example :)